# Pub external dependency

Tags: npm, dart, dart-pub

How can I use external dependencies with pub? For example I want to include Materialize-css and use it in my scss file. If I install it using npm than pub can't locate it in node_modules folder. If I put it into web folder it puts all the source in build folder, which is not what I want.

So what is the correct way to include external files?

Answer (score 0):

`pub` currently doesn't integrate with other package managers.

You might want to exclude files.

```
transformers:
  $dart2js:
  - exclude: "**/*.scss"
```

Not sure if this really works for your use case. I haven't tried this myself yet.
See https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/search?p=2&q=exclude&utf8=%E2%9C%93 for exclude pattern examples.